# character counter in 2D array

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a 2D array and place four `X` in the same column. I created a loop for detecting and counting the number of `X`s but it doesn't work.

```
 var creatematrix = function (nbRang, nbColumn) {
    var result = Array(nbRang);
    for (var i=0; i<nbRang; i++) {
        result[i] = Array(nbColumn);
    }
    return result;
};

var m = creatematrix(2, 6);

m[1][2] = "X";
m[1][3] = "X";
m[1][4] = "X";
m[1][5] = "X";

   var sumX = 0

   for(var k = 0; k < 6 ; k++){



                  if(m[1][k]== "X"){
                    sumX += 1;   

             }else if(sumX == 4){

                   alert("player won");  
                }   

   }
```

Comment: `for(var k = 6; k <= 6 ; k--)` <--

Comment: *"why is there an infinite loop on my program?"* Because you put it there ;) `k` will always be `<= 6`, since you start at `6` and always decrement the number.

Comment: Once I noticed bugs with `--` in JS. So I always try `++` instead.

Comment: @nooby102030: Because in each iteration your are resetting `sumX` to to `0`. Initialize the variable outside of the loop.

Comment: btw, there is also a Typo: result[i] = Array(nbColomun);  should be result[i] = Array(nbColumn);

Comment: Please update your question to what you are really asking instead of asking new questions in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will never hit `sumX == 4` because it falls into the first if statement on the last check and then the loop is over. You should do the check in another if statement instead of an else if.

```
if(m[1][k]== "X"){
    sumX += 1;
}
if(sumX == 4){
    alert("player won");
    break;
}
```